# Any good smartphone simulators available?

Tags: android, iphone, html5

I'm trying to find a good smartphone simulator to test HTML5 games on. Doesn't matter if it is only 1 phone or a library of phones, iOS or android. As long as it's as close as it can get to the touchscreen experience.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the Tegra Android Development Pack. It includes Android simulator, the SDK and preinstalled Eclipse just in case: http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack

Then go to the android-sdk-windows folder and open AVD Manager.exe. In that screen you can create a new emulated device with any specs you want. Then use Start to open it. It will have internet connection so you can try your remote app.

The thing is that none of the emulators (iOS/Android) are near the performance most devices would give you, so you can't measure performance and framerate.

Comment: Excellent thanks, it's not for performance testing i just want to play around with touch features without having to buy a device :).